# Rspec Stub array iteration key

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```
releases.each do |release|
   if release.tag_name == "v0.0.0"

   end
end
```

I was wondering how you can stub `release.tag_name` to return "v0.0.0" in rspec. Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you want this for all the elements in `releases`??

Comment: Sorry, I updated. I want to stub `release.tag_name`.

Comment: how do you know which of `release` you want to stub its `tag_name`

Comment: Yes, I want to to stub for every element of `release`. I skimmed your comment too quickly and misinterpreted it. It would be great if I could use something like `should_receive` with `releases.tag_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stub all the `release` in `releases` I would do as below:

```
releases.map { |release| release.stub(:tag_name) { "v0.0.0" } }
```

example:

```
require 'rspec'

a = "3"
describe do
  it do
    a.stub(:to_i) { "stubed"}
    puts a.to_i #=> "stubed"
  end
end
```

Link to [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-3/docs/method-stubs/stub-with-a-simple-return-value)